# How to change the text color in an Excel shape?

Tags: ms-office

I am trying to change the text color specifically for a `diamond`. The background fill defaults unfortunately to `blue` -which I changed to `white` .. which is the *same color as their choice for text* .  Polar bear in a blizzard anyone?

[image]

"Look ma they can't see me !"

[image]

The funny thing is - the `rounded rectangle` *does* allow changing the text color:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *whatever reason* the option to set text color has been neglected in the `Format Shape` panel on the right side.  However I noticed it *can* be set in the `Main Ribbon`

[image]